# Crash on clicking full screen ads using google ad mob

Tags: android, admob

I have implemented Google ads by using this library
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'

Below code

```
 mAdView = new AdManagerAdView(getActivity());
    adContainerView = view.findViewById(R.id.ad_view_container);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(adID);
    request = new AdManagerAdRequest.Builder().build();
    adSize = getAdSize();
    // Step 4 - Set the adaptive ad size on the ad view.
    mAdView.setAdSize(adSize);
    adContainerView.addView(mAdView);
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

But getting crash on clicking some ads
Process: com.indiatoday.mobiletak, PID: 13897
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy12 cannot be cast to com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.c(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573506031:5)
at com.android.webview.chromium.N.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573506031:44)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)

Please help not get the way out.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You cannot do much here as this is caused by Chromium / WebView afaik. If you are able to reproduce this issue on emulator or physical device then try updating the webview from google play.

Comment: Thank @Darshan. But I need to find out a solution, as my app user facing this crash on clicking ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, find that bug. Actually, it was due to a third-party SDK clarity, which tracks tap events on the app. That's why on clicking ads they were crashing.

Thanks